# Get data from StreamContent into Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

In a view, I have the following code:

```
@model Project.Models.DrugEntry

<body>
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "createDrug", @action = "/api/DrugEntry" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add a new Drug Entry</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NDC)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NDC)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NDC)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dosage)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dosage)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dosage)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Brand)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Brand)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Brand)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Generic)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Generic)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Generic)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Add to Database" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
</body>
```

Simply put, it's four text input boxes and a submit button for creating a DrugEntry with an NDC, Dosage, Brand, and Generic name. When receiving it in my Controller, it comes in as a StreamContent object. I've searched all over SO, but most answers use an HttpClient() and require a static web address, and I don't know what that is or why it'd be used. I can view the garbled information using

```
response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
```

so I know the information is getting here, but how do I easily and simply extract it?

Comment: (I'm not the biggest WebApi expert) Why a StreamContent? Can't you just post data and have the model binding take care of it in your WebApi post action (using the model as a parameter)?

Comment: The issue I run into is that for a file upload system that also interacts with my Controller, the function that receives input from the page is an async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFormData(). Mind you, I'm a complete noob to this.